# Can't select regexs from webpage to validate text

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to validate some user input English phrases against regular expressions (to allow for some variation). An example is "Where can you go?" against `/^(W|w){1}here\s{1,2}can\s{1,2}you\s{1,2}go\s{0,1}\??$/`  I'm using a jquery ui dialog which contains a form with id `"form#t2e_form"` and an input with  id `"form#t2e_w"`. Here is the code:

```
jQuery("span.t2e_icon").on("click", function(evnt) { 
  t2e_dlog.dialog("open");
  evnt.stopPropagation();
  // remove the dialog box title bar
  jQuery("#ui-dialog-title-dialog").hide();
  jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header');       
  var elementId = evnt.target.id,
  englishTextId = ("span#t1ee" + elementId.substring(7)),
  regexId = ("regex" + elementId.substring(7)),

  regexText =( /^(W|w){1}here\s{1,2}can\s{1,2}you\s{1,2}go\s{0,1}\??$/);    
  var form_config  ='<div id="t2e_modal"><p>Please enter the English text here</p><form id="t2e_form" action="#"><input type="text" id="t2e_w" name="t2e_w"          size=50><input id="t2e_submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></form><span id="output"></span></div>';
  jQuery("div#t2e_dialog").append(form_config);
  jQuery( "form#t2e_form" ).submit(function(event) { 
      if (regexText.test(jQuery( "input#t2e_w" ).val())) {
      jQuery( "span#output" ).text( "Validated..." ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
    } else {                                                                                                                                 
      jQuery( "span#output" ).text( "Not valid!" ).show().fadeOut( 1000 );
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

This works but if the following value of regexText is substituted so that other regexs can be selected (as in the html below) then the code fails

```
regexText = document.getElementById(regexId).innerHTML;
```

The relevant html is:

```
  <p id="regex01">/^(W|w){1}here\s{1,2}can\s{1,2}you\s{1,2}go\s{0,1}\??$/ </p>
  <p id="regex02">/^(W|w){1}here\s{1,2}can\s{1,2}you\s{1,2}work\s{0,1}\??$/ </p>
  ...
```

If anyone can help that would be great, thanks

Comment: FYI, `(W|w)` is `[Ww]` and `{0,1}` is `?`

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? It doesn't match when it should? Matches when it shouldn't? Doesn't output anything? Returns an error? Anyway; I think the problem might be that you're passing a string, not a regex, to regexText. Try `regexText = new regex(document.getElementById(regexId).innerHTML);`

Comment: I've removed the {1}s and changed the code as suggested, tho shouldn't regex be RegExp? In any case I tried both and RegExp returned "Not Valid" when the correct phrase was entered and the dialog was blank (i.e. no form was displayed) with "regex".